# Pascal's Triangle II : Java : Can it done in O(1) space complexity?

Tags: java

- Input: 3
- Output: [1,3,3,1]

link to the question is https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/recursion-i/251/scenario-i-recurrence-relation/3234/

My Solution is

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> getRow(int rowIndex) {
        List<Integer> pascalList = new ArrayList<>();

        rowIndex += 1;
        int c = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= rowIndex ; i++) {
            pascalList.add(c);
            c = c * (rowIndex-i)/i;
        }
        return pascalList;
    }
}
```

Which I got this:- 
[image]

Could you optimize your algorithm to use only O(k) extra space? Above Solution takes O(1) space

I think it's because of the `range issue`; How can I stop overflow?

Comment: You don't need to store the list elements explicitly: look at how to use `AbstractList` in the Javadoc.

Comment: For dealing with the overflow: use an element type with a wider range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to store all your calculations as long, and then convert the final List into an integer List. (However, this uses O(k) extra space)

Here is the code for that:

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> getRow(int rowIndex) {
        List<Long> pascalList = new ArrayList<>();

        rowIndex += 1;
        long c = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= rowIndex ; i++) {
            pascalList.add(c);
            c = c*(rowIndex-i)/i;       
        }
        List<Integer>ans = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<rowIndex;i++){
            ans.add((int)(long)pascalList.get(i));
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Another solution:

The largest element is going to be 33 choose 17, which is 1166803110 (fits into Integer without overflow).

The reason your code gives overflow is because you have

```
c = c * (rowIndex-i)/i;
```

Note that c will multiply itself by (rowIndex-i) before dividing, which could result in an overflow - that is, c*(rowIndex-i) could be larger than the maximum integer value.

To prevent this, we can divide by i first if there is no remainder.
If there is a remainder, we can store the value as a double, and after multiplying by c, hope that there was no precision error (Note that this may not always work due to this precision error, but in our case we got lucky)

Here is the code that beats 100.00% of Java submissions.

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> getRow(int rowIndex) {
        List<Integer> pascalList = new ArrayList<>();

        rowIndex += 1;
        int c = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= rowIndex ; i++) {
            pascalList.add(c);
            if(c%i==0){
                 c = c/i*(rowIndex-i);
            }else{
                c = (int)(c*((rowIndex-i)/(double)i));
            }

        }
        return pascalList;
    }
}
```